# Staining a Pressure treated deck

Tags: deck, staining

I installed a PT Deck in June. Wanted to get protection on it before winter set in, so pressure washed it & let it dry 1 week. I then stained it with a quality semi-transparent oil based stain. Not happy with the results. It looks as the stain didn't absorb evenly across the deck. Some parts are Great,others show more color. Suggestions on how to deal with this.

Comment: Welcome to DIY.SE! How many coats of stain did you apply? Can you post a picture? Different boards absorb the stain differently (even within the same board), so what you're seeing may be normal.